# Setting a subdomain to access home machine with windows remote desktop

Tags: remote-desktop, home-server, subdomain

I'm trying to remotely connect to home machine through Windows Remote Desktop (amongst other things, but this is currently my primary focus). I can do this fine using my home WAN's static IP (thank god for cable!) with port-forwarding, but I would like to access it from a subdomain of my web-site (e.g. home.mydomain.co.uk).

In the cPanel for my hosting account, I've gone into DNS zones and altered the A-record to point to my WAN's IP, which I thought *should* do the job, but I still cannot connect. When I ping the subdomain, I get my web-host's IP, which I guess is to be expected as I believe the DNS of the host domain is used first, then my server handles the redirection of traffic to the IP in the A-record. Is this the correct idea? Do A-record changes suffer from the same propagation delays as DNS record changes, as I suppose that could explain it?

(by the way, this thread confirms my thoughts that setting the A-record should be enough: [Hostmonster Subdomain redirected to home server IP: How to ssh into home server using subdomain](https://superuser.com/questions/299638/hostmonster-subdomain-redirected-to-home-server-ip-how-to-ssh-into-home-server))

Comment: If they are cached locally or the DNS server you use is serving cached entries and the TTL has not passed, then yes you have to wait it out. You should set a really low TTL for that entry/zone if you plan on updating it frequently.

Comment: Yeah it's working now - I guess I was just being impatient! Thanks for your advice on TTL - I'm fairly new to the whole remote access thing!